# Bootstrap Vue: Select form placeholder not showing

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, html-select

I have a Bootstrap Vue form with a select element. I would like the select element to show a placeholder when nothing is chosen. The problem is that the select element renders empty until you choose an option.

Anyone have any clue on how to fix this?

```
<!-- COMPANY FILTER -->
        <div class="company-search" v-if="this.users.length != 0">
            <!-- @change="filterByCompany" -->
            <b-form @change="filterUsers">
                <b-form-group id="select-company-form-group" label="Filter by company:" label-for="select-company">
                    <b-icon icon="list" class="company-search-icon"></b-icon>
                    <b-form-select
                    id="select-company"
                    v-model="selectedCompany"
                    :options="[{ value: null, text: 'Select One' }, 'ALTiPROSJEKT AS', 'AiP BETONGSAGING AS', 'AiP ENTREPENØR AS', 'AiP SANERING AS', 'AiP UTLEIE AS']"
                    >
                    </b-form-select>
                </b-form-group>
            </b-form>
        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are some great examples on here: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select they talk you through the different ways of setting default values.

To disable your placeholder value all you have to do is this:

```
:options="[{ value: null, text: 'Select One', disabled: true }, 'ALTiPROSJEKT AS', 'AiP BETONGSAGING AS', 'AiP ENTREPENØR AS', 'AiP SANERING AS', 'AiP UTLEIE AS']"
```

Comment: I've been looking through the docs, but i could not find a solution to the problem. In all of the examples the first option is the placeholder.

I tried setting ```selected: true``` in the object in the first option, but it still shows empty.

Thank you for answering :)

Comment: The v-model variable "selected" is the default value which will be the selected one. In the case of the first example it is null, so that means the option with the value of null will be selected

Comment: Thank you. Since the v-model variable is an empty string, i had to change the value of the object in the first option to an empty string like this: ```{ value: '', text: 'Filter by company' }```. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I use this trick in production forms; it works well. Also make sure that you when you process the form, put in an extra check so you're not passing it as an option.